# In jQuery, what is the difference between `this.element` and `this.element[/* some number */]`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I came across the following in a piece of code:

```
var searchBox = $(this.element[0]);
```

I'm pretty new to Javascript and jQuery. I am trying to understand it but i am having a hard time. This line is in an implementation of jQuery UI Accordion widget.

What does the `this` refer to?

Also, I played a bit with the line and I came to an understanding that it works perfectly - no matter what number is in the array. In addition, if I remove the brackets and just write the following line, it works just fine:

```
var searchBox = $(this.element);
```

What is it means and what is the difference?

Thank you very much. :)

**Edit:**
Here is my full code. Maybe it could help. https://jsfiddle.net/yx8puo2j/1/

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work), it has a detailed explanation on how `this` work.

Comment: "What does the `this` refer to?" - it depends on the context.

Comment: Assuming `this.element` refers to a jQuery object (selected previously) then `$(this.element[0])` creates a *new* jQuery object of just the first selected (DOM) element. It could also be written as [`this.element.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/). However, `this.element[0]` will work in others cases - eg. not just jQuery objects - such as normal Arrays and HTMLCollections..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var searchBox = $(this.element[0]);
```

returns **one** element (1 object).

```
var searchBox = $(this.element);
```

return a **list** of elements.

This states for **`classes`**, not for **`id`** (cause `id` is unique).

> Examples:
>
> - `var searchbox = $(this.angry_button)` returns all (**list**) elements with class `angry_button`.
> - `var searchbox = $(this.angry_button[0])` returns the **first** element with class `angry_button`.
> - `var searchbox = $(this.angry_button[1])` returns the **second** element with class `angry_button`.

Comment: But why does it work for every number I use? I have only one `input` element with a `id="searchBox"` as shown in the code, so why does `var searchBox = $(this.element);` works exactly like `var searchBox = $(this.element[0]);` or even `var searchBox = $(this.element[-1]);`?

Comment: Are you Greek ? (curiousity)

Comment: Lol, not. Israeli. :)

Comment: ∏ (pi) is israeli too ?

Comment: It's not Pi, it's the hebrew letter [Heth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heth). :)

Why class and not id?

Comment: Oops... I mean use `var searchbox = $("#searchbox");`. Keep it simple.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87361/discussion-between-sipo-and-strukt).

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
var searchBox = $(this.element[0]);
```

You're selecting the first

> element

of "This" where "This" is the element you're currently in like a div or an input field

Answer (score 1):

I cant tell you what this is, but I can explain a bit what happens and why it works:

In jQuery you can select any element with `$("")`, but what if you select an class that exists multiple times in the DOM??
So I got this button class that exists 5 times in the document and i select it with `$(".button")` . This now returns an array with 5 items in it.

If we want to select the first button that would be `$(".button[0]")` if we want to select the fifth button that would be `$(".button[4]")`

---

so basically you are selecting element n within the page that has that specific identifier.